# Why is `typedef void * COMPLEX` used in this interface?

Tags: c, struct, typedef, void-pointers

I have a program and I can't understant how it works. Here is a part of it. 
I don't understand the line `typedef void *COMPLEX`, the command `this` and why the `struct COMPLEX_IMPL` is being used.

```
#ifndef _COMPLEX_H 
#define _COMPLEX_H 

typedef void *COMPLEX; 

COMPLEX NewCOMPLEX (double a, double b ); 

void DeleteCOMPLEX(COMPLEX this ); 

double GetA (COMPLEX this ); 

double GetB (COMPLEX this ); 

COMPLEX AddComplex (COMPLEX c1, COMPLEX c2, COMPLEX res); 
COMPLEX MultComplex (COMPLEX c1, COMPLEX c2, COMPLEX res); 

#endif /* _COMPLEX_H */

#ifndef _COMPLEX_H 
#define _COMPLEX_H 

typedef void *COMPLEX; 

COMPLEX NewCOMPLEX (double a, double b ); 

void DeleteCOMPLEX(COMPLEX this ); 

double GetA (COMPLEX this ); 

double GetB (COMPLEX this ); 

COMPLEX AddComplex (COMPLEX c1, COMPLEX c2, COMPLEX res); 
COMPLEX MultComplex (COMPLEX c1, COMPLEX c2, COMPLEX res); 

#endif /* _COMPLEX_H */
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include "complex.h" 

struct COMPLEX_IMPL { double a; double b; }; 

double GetA(COMPLEX this) { 
    struct COMPLEX_IMPL *this_impl = (struct COMPLEX_IMPL*)this; 
    return this_impl->a; 
}
```

Comment: From this I would guess this is C++? Anyway, please look at the basics of the language this application is using and you should be able to answer your question yourself.

Comment: @steffinchen On the contrary, due to the use of `this` as an ordinary identifier, this is a C program that is not valid C++. I would recommend that you study the basics of C++ more closely. It would also be better if you refrained from making such derisive comments; the use of `void *` here is not a basic matter.

Answer (score 8):

`typedef` defines a name for a type. So

```
typedef void *COMPLEX;
COMPLEX z;
```

is equivalent to

```
void *z;
```

A pointer type normally indicates what kind of data the pointer points to. `void *` is an exception: it's a way to have a pointer without saying what the type of the value it points to is. You can freely assign any kind of pointer to a `void *` pointer and back.

`void *` pointers are normally used in generic library functions that must work with data of any type. For example, consider the standard library function `memcpy`:

```
void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n);
```

You pass that function a pointer to an object of any type `src`, a pointer to another object (which is usually, but not always, of the same type) `dest`, and a number of bytes to copy. The function copies the bytes, it doesn't care what the bytes mean, so it's enough to pass two pointers-to-an-unspecified-type.

The use of `void *` here is not good or common programming practice. A complex number is represented as its real part and its imaginary part:

```
struct COMPLEX_IMPL { double a; double b; };
```

A typical complex number library would make this the `COMPLEX` type.

The code you posted hides the implementation of the `COMPLEX` type. The fact that complex numbers are implemented as a structure containing two `double` members is only apparent in `complex.c`. Users of the library only see that a `COMPLEX` is a pointer to something. This is a form of [data abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_%28computer_science%29#Data_abstraction): hiding the representation details of a data type. But it's poorly done: with this definition, any pointer to anything can be assigned to a `COMPLEX`. The normal way is to use an [incomplete structure](http://c-faq.com/struct/opaquetypes.html), which is declared and visibly a structure but whose members are not specified. In `complex.h`, you would write:

```
struct COMPLEX_IMPL;
typedef struct COMPLEX_IMPL *COMPLEX;
```

That way, the only way to legally create a `COMPLEX_IMPL` is through the functions provided by `complex.h`, but a variable of type `COMPLEX` is visibly a pointer to a representation of a complexe number as defined in `complex.c`.

Oh, and `this` is an ordinary variable name.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef void *COMPLEX;
```

makes `COMPLEX` an alias for the type `void *`. (This is evil, btw., since you shouldn't use a pointer typedef and a `void` one effectively turns off type checking.)

There is no "command" `this`, that's just the name of an argument.

The `struct` is used to keep the `a` and `b` members together. That's what structs are for.

Comment: _makes COMPLEX an alias for the type void *._

What do you mean with this ?? I can't get it... :/

Comment: @ΕμμανουήλΒαρέσης: do you know anything about C?

Comment: Because apparently you don't know about basic language constructs like `typedef`. Better pick up a good book on C.

Comment: It's just a subject at my university and I'm having a test in C tomorrow. My teacher had never teached us this construct but he is asking it. That's why I'm a bit stuck.

Does the line `typedef void *COMPLEX;` creates a general pointer and then this general type is used in this line `COMPLEX NewCOMPLEX (double a, double b );` because we don't know what type the function returns ?

Answer (score 0):

- `typedef void* COMPLEX` makes 'COMPLEX' an alias for the void pointer type 'void*'
- COMPLEX_IMPL is use because a complex number has two parts, so this groups them together
- 'this' is a variable

I think a tutorial in C would benefit you greatly here.

Comment: It doesn't do anything really - it's a pointer to something of unknown type. Often it's used as a middle-man when performing incompatible casting operations, amongst other things. The usage in this example does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: Ok but if it doesn't do something, then why it exists in the program,

Comment: `typedef void *COMPLEX; `

`COMPLEX NewCOMPLEX (double a, double b );`

Namely, he uses the command `typedef void *COMPLEX` to create a general pointer and then he uses this type (COMPLEX) to the function NewCOMPLEX because he doesn't know what type the function returns ?

Answer (score 0):

typedef void*

use to define function in dll which used by your project