# what's the use of '(void)' in code line 1?

Tags: c++

I'm practicing the reflection in C++, and the code is as follows:

```
typedef void* (*PTRCreateObject)(void); 
class ClassFactory{
private:
    map<string, PTRCreateObject>m_classMap;
    ClassFactory(){};    
public:
    void* getClassByName(string className);
    void registClass(string name, PTRCreateObject method);
    static ClassFactory& getInstance();    
};
```

Comment: it takes no arguments.

Comment: `PTRCreateObject` is a pointer to a function which takes no arguments and returns a `void *`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is \`typedef void \* COMPLEX\` used in this interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412262/why-is-typedef-void-complex-used-in-this-interface)

Comment: What do *you* think `PTRCreateObject` is? What do *you* think `(void)` would do?

Comment: (void) in C takes nothing as arguments,and () can take any number of arguments.In C++ both means same.

Answer (score 4):

It's a carryover from C.

### In C

`void* (*)(void)` is a pointer to a function that takes **no** parameters.

`void* (*)()` is a pointer to a function that takes **unspecified** parameters.

### In C++

Both mean **no** parameters.

`()` is idiomatic and `(void)` was allowed for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

It is just another way of representing no parameters.

```
typedef void* (*PTRCreateObject)(void);
```

and

```
typedef void* (*PTRCreateObject)();
```

are both equivalent.

the return signature `void*`  is just returning a pointer to some unknown type.